# Weird error when replacing elements in 2d array

Tags: python

```
in_file = open("3.8.2.txt",'r')


height = 8
width = 11
board = []
liner = []
for i in range(200):
    liner.append("0")
for i in range(200):
    board.append(liner)

for i in range(height):
    line = in_file.readline().strip("\n").lower()
    for j in range(len(line)):
        board[50 + i][50 + j] = line[j]
```

I am trying to place a 2d board around a bunch of 0's. Instead of getting a nice board in the middle, the last line of the board is placed in the middle of each line on the board. I have no idea why.

**Here's the output:**

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000yuiqlxcnbjf000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000yuiqlxcnbjf000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000yuiqlxcnbjf000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000yuiqlxcnbjf000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000yuiqlxcnbjf000000000000000000000000
```

**My expected output would be something like this:**

```
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000letterss00000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000letterss00000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000letterss00000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000letterss00000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000letterss00000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: @thefourtheye You're right, sorry about that :)

Comment: @ShashankGupta Thats okay :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual problem is in these line

```
for i in range(200):
    board.append(liner)
```

You are not creating 200 new lists and appending it to `board`. Instead, you are adding 200 references to the same list in board. What you should do is, create a copy of the `linear` and append it to board like this

```
for i in range(200):
    board.append(liner[:])
```

The board preparation can be written like this

```
board = [["0"] * 200 for _ in range(200)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i can't believe the slicing messed everything up